# git svn clone error during project migration

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to migrate whole SVN repository to GIT repository. I've created dump file and loaded it using svnadmin load to local directory. Last thing to do was to copy SVN repo to GIT using git svn clone. Here is the whole command:

```
git svn clone file:///c/Users/60051741/Desktop/DumpRepo /C:/Users/60051741/Desktop/Projects/git_repo
```

and  after that i get an error:

```
mkdir /C:: Permission denied at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 547.
```

This line in git-svn file looks like this:

```
mkpath([$repo_path]) unless -d $repo_path;
```

Is there any way to solve this probleb and what might be a reason of this problem?

This is all for Windows local pc. SVN version: 1.8.17 (r1770682), git version: svn, version 1.8.17 (r1770682). 
In some artickles i've read, that a "-r" or "-r19815:HEAD" command might help, but in my situation, no success.

Comment: I'm guessing you need `C:/Users/60051741/Desktop/Projects/git_repo` instead of `/C:/Users/60051741/Desktop/Projects/git_repo` (note there's no leading slash)

Comment: It worked, thank you!